# Does bad karma done in God's consciousness have consequences?

Tags: scripture, karma

Does a karma which is considered bad, but is done in God's consciousness have consequences?

Comment: can you give an example ? what does "done in God's consciousness" mean ?

Comment: @ram knowing everything in physical world to be one, knowing God to be the cause of everything and be everything, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by bad karma? When Bhagavan is embodiment of good, how can one immersed in God can do anything bad?

Comment: @Partha From what I know, Bhagavan is Nirguna and good/bad does not exist in his realm. Good/Bad applies to those who are under effect of Maya (when part of physical manifestation)

Comment: Brahman is Nirguna.But Bhagavan is always Saguna.This follows from the two definitions of Bhagavan available in our scriptures

Comment: @Partha What is the difference between Brahman and Bhagavan?

Comment: Brahman is both Saguna and Nirguna.Saguna Brahman is Bhagavan, who has all good qualities. you can get the difference in previous answers of such questions in this site

Comment: If a person truly has God consciousness, then he is incapable of doing an evil action. This does NOT mean that anything he does is good, that he can do an evil action and say it is really good; but rather that he is incapable of doing anything that might be considered evil.

Comment: After attaining god consciousness I.e. Brahma jnana dronaacharya decided to fight kill 10000 people min daily so self surrender to god is the key here if onethinks god only telling me to do bad things then it's sure step to andhamas

Comment: Answer is Yes andhmas is welcoming him